# How to create a dataframe from series object when iterating

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating and as a result of a single iteration I acquire a pandas series object which looks like this:

```
DE_AT    118.55
DE_CZ     62.73
PL_DE    263.36
PL_SK    315.07
dtype: float64
```

Sometimes I might get different names and lengths of this series for example I might get:

```
DE_AT    118.55
DE_CZ     62.73
PL_DE    263.36
PL_NL    315.07
PL_UK    420
dtype: float64
```

Now I want to create a dataframe from these series objects when iterating such that I will have all names as the index, from these two series objects I would like to get:

```
index      1        2
DE_AT    118.55   118.55
DE_CZ    62.73    62.73
PL_DE    263.36   263.36
PL_SK    315.07    NaN
PL_NL    NaN      315.07
PL_UK    NaN       420
```

Or maybe I can store them in a list and later create a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Basic outer join of two series:

```
s1=pd.Series(index=["DE_AT","DE_CZ","PL_DE", "PL_SK"], data=[1,2,3,4]).to_frame()
s2=pd.Series(index=["DE_AT","DE_CZ","PL_DE", "PL_NL", "PL_UK"], data=[1,2,3,4,5]).to_frame()

s1.join(s2, how="outer",lsuffix="1",rsuffix="2")
```

**Output:**

| index | 00 | 01 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DE_AT | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| DE_CZ | 2.0 | 2.0 |
| PL_DE | 3.0 | 3.0 |
| PL_NL | NaN | 4.0 |
| PL_SK | 4.0 | NaN |
| PL_UK | NaN | 5.0 |